# Xamarin.Forms How do I get Intent to work?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-intent

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution and am finding it difficult to implement the Intent class as this library is part of Android.Content.

My solution has 2 projects. Project1 & Project1.Android.

I cannot seem to use the following in my Project1 project:

using Android.Content;
using Android.App;

Am I missing something here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I need to use Intent to broadcast a message to another app on the Android device.

using Android.Content;
using Android.App;

Comment: `Project1` is shared between all platforms, so you cannot generally use platform specific code.  Android code should go in the Android project

Comment: You need to check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Answer (score 0):

Since your app is a Xamarin.Form app, you cannot invoke code from android platform directly. But you can use `DependencyService` to invoke android platform code from shared code. The [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.dependencyservice?view=xamarin-forms) class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code.

From official document [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction), we could know that the process for using the `DependencyService` to invoke native platform functionality is to:

> 1.Create an interface for the native platform functionality, in shared code. For more information, see Create an interface.
>
> 2.Implement the interface in the required platform projects. For more information, see Implement the interface on each platform.
>
> 3.Register the platform implementations with the DependencyService. This enables Xamarin.Forms to locate the platform implementations at
> runtime. For more information, see Register the platform
> implementations.
>
> 4.Resolve the platform implementations from shared code, and invoke them. For more information, see Resolve the platform implementations.

For more information, please check document: [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

And there is an official sample about this, you can check it here: [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/dependencyservice/)